# How do I add connectors between shapes in Visio Pro 2016?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I think I'm missing something quite basic about Visio.  I can't add connectors between shapes.  I can create connections that appear to be attached to shapes, but when I move the shape, the connector endpoints stay where they were.

I have found instructions in the app's Help, which seem to correspond to this [Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Add-connectors-between-shapes-in-Visio-eaa045c8-5ce9-4d4b-bd30-bb87dc8ac65a).  Where that page says I should position the Connector tool over the center of the first shape until a green box appears, I never see a green box.  I can't get dynamic or point connections to work.

Comment: The gif in the section ` To connect shapes by using the Connector tool ` shows it perfectly. The 'Green flash' has to appear in order that they connected. Did you try the connector tool as well? And it also did not work?

Answer (score 0):

When a connector is glued to a shape the handle should turn red, not green. Green is used to indicate Snap, red is Glue.
You might also need to check your **Snap and Glue** settings, this was on the **View -> Visual Aids** ribbon (then use the little arrow) in Visio 2013, I don't know if it is still hidden in the same way.